# How to retrieve a phase gate from a circuit made out of $CX$ and $T$

Tags: circuit-construction, gate-synthesis

The extract below comes from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.07363.pdf).

[image]

It is an example that shows a basic phase polynomial, related to the $CCZ$ gate.

It can also be written with $CX$ and $T$ gates.

I can't find the connection between the function $P$ and the circuit.

Why the $CX$ and $T$ gates are placed that way?

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a bit with value $x_1$ and you apply a $T$ gate to it, you're going to get a phase of angle $x_1\pi/4$. Do another $T$ gate on a bit with value $x_2$ and you're up to a total phase of $(x_1+x_2)\pi/4$. For simplicity, ignore the $\pi/4$ component, so you just write down $x_1+x_2$, except that you have to remember that everything was orignally up to a modulo $2\pi$ which, having factored out a $\pi/4$, means you're doing integer arithmetic modulo 8.

The circuit diagram does a really good job of the calculations that the cnots do so that you know what bit values each phase gate is acting on. Just remember that $T^\dagger$ gives you a phase of $-\pi/4\equiv 7\pi/4$, so that counts as 7 in the integer arithmetic.

So, just run through a phase gate at a time and add it up. The first column gave $x_1+x_2$. Then the $T^\dagger$ gives $7x_1\oplus x_3$. Then the next gives $7x_2\oplus x_3$ and so on.